# Cordova plugins to non-cordova Android Project

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview, cordova-plugins

Can somebody tell me if I can add some Cordova plugins to my existing non-cordova Android Studio project?

Comment: hi friend i think its no admit for android studio , the best way to add pluggins cordova its add to a project cordova

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer i can move on now! 
It remains for me to see how to convert my project into a project cordova..

Comment: you welcome ! if you want to move to project cordova , only create your project from console and move all your views and js to www folder on cordova project, if my answer was good to you, please send me a like , so thanks man

Comment: Yes of course you can ADD (copy) them (I do it all the time). You DOWNLOAD them to a dummy cordova project and copy them into your Android studio (I then use gradle build).